Prove The class Recset of recursive sets is the same as the class of all sets.
This is from spring18 mcs.pdf.
recursive set definition

Definition 8.3.1. The class of recursive sets Recset is defined as follows:
Base case: The empty set $\varnothing$ is a Recset.
Constructor step: If S is a nonempty set of Recset’s, then S is a Recset.

What to prove

Theorem 8.3.2. The class Recset of recursive sets is the same as the class of all
sets.
Proof. Everything in Recset is a set by definition, so we need only show that every
set is in Recset.
Suppose to the contrary that a set S is not in Recset. So S must have an ele-
ment $N_0$ that is not in Recset, since otherwise S would by definition be in Recset.
Likewise, $N_0$ must have an element $N_1$ that is not in Recset, and $N_1$ must have an
element $N_2$ that is not in Recset, and so on. So we have an infinite sequence
$$
S \ni N_0 \ni N_1 \ni N_2 \ni \ldots
$$
Therefore the set$^8$
$$
T ::= \{S, N_0 , N_1 , N_2 , \ldots\}
$$
has no member-minimal element, in violation of Foundation.
$^8$A rigorous proof, which we are skipping, requires careful use of the Choice axiom to prove that
T is a set.


I prove $T$ is one set as follows:
Here let the family of sets be
$U,S,N_{0,\cdots}$ where $U$ is the universal set.
Then let the choice function be
$U\to S,S\to N_0,\cdots$. Then $T$ is the indexed set.

I have questions about the "infinite sequence" part of the proof.
Suppose one set $S=\{1\}$ is not in Recset.

Based on the Constructor step, since at each step we can only have elements from Recset and the Base case only has $\varnothing$, then Recset should only have $\varnothing$ as its minimal unit similar to von Neumann ordinals.
Let us follow the process in "Proof". Then $N_0=1$. But now we can't proceed further since $1$ isn't one set.

What is wrong about my process after assuming $S=\{1\}$?

What do you mean by “$1$”? The usual definition is $$1={\emptyset}.$$

@MJD Thanks. If so, what if the set element is something not is ordinal or natural number? Does the question imply that we give all elements of all sets one implicit unique ordinal?

If you're not already familiar with set theory then the level of axiomatic set theory this set of notes is unloading while omitting key steps seems quite ambitious to me! This is not straightforward stuff. The point is that when you're working in ZFC, there is no such thing as a set with an element that's not a set. This isn't even an axiom. If you want to understand what's even going on, I would first make sure you really understand everything sections 8.3 and 3.6 say. In particular, in 8.3: "So the domain of discourse of ZFC is the pure sets" is important.

@IzaakvanDongen Thanks for your clarification. I read that sentence in 8.3 a few days ago. I didn't pay much attention to that until you highlighted that. If all elements are pure sets, then the infinite sequence is reasonable now. P.s. I didn't learn about pure set theory before. So when the book gives me ZFC, I connected them to the normal knowledge I have learned in calculus subconsciously which causes the above wrong proof of mine.

"pure sets" is also consistent with "Constructor step".

Not everything is an ordinal. For example, ${1}$ is not an ordinal.

Thanks for your clarification. When I finished reading required CS books, It seems that I should take some time to learn set theory specifically if I want to understand this problem more.

It might also be worth mentioning that some set theories contain objects called “urelements” (or sometimes “atoms”) that can be members of sets but which are “not sets” in the sense that don't have members themselves.  The current ZF theory does not contain urelements, but the original design of it in 1908 did.
